# Issue Removing DB2 Database

Tags: database, db2

So I screwed up. I was trying to free up some disk space and accidentally deleted logs DB2 needed to connect to/start my database. 
I'd run into this before, so I uncataloged the database and deleted the files on disk so I could recreate it. However, when I go to recreate the database, I get:

**SQL1005N  The database alias "BGTRUNK" already exists in either the local
database directory or system database directory.**

db2 list database directory shows that it's gone. Everything else I saw searching around suggests recatalogging and dropping the db, but that's obviously not an option at this stage.

How can I free this alias up for reuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find a workaround. The issue was that I had deleted the SQL000* folder that contained the database, but the database alias was still cataloged in the SQLDBDIR file. I couldn't just delete and start fresh because I had several other databases that would be lost by doing so.
I was able to see what it used to be called by re-cataloging the database and running

db2 list db directory on C:\

which had output like:

```
Database 3 entry:    
Database alias                       = BGTRUNK
Database name                        = BGTRUNK
Database directory                   = SQL00002
Database release level               = f.00
Comment                              =
Directory entry type                 = Home
Catalog database partition number    = 0
Database member number               = 0
```

SQL00002 didn't exist anymore, but I recreated it using data from one of the databases that I had. That was enough to convince db2 that the database existed so I could successfully drop.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible reasons:

1) The alias already exists in the system database directory but not in the local database directory -

To  solve it using DB2 CLI  run

***db2 uncatalog database BGTRUNK***

2) The alias already exists in the local database directory but not in the system database directory.

To  solve it using DB2 CLI  run

***db2 catalog database BGTRUNK***

***db2 drop database BGTRUNK***

Comment: I already tried all that. Uncatalog completes successfully but the alias is still in use. I can't catalog and drop the database because it's been deleted on disk.